# How to check if site is in maintenance mode in Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x

I need to determine if the site is in maintenance mode.

Pseudo code:

```
if (*site is in maintenance mode*) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do this other thing
}
```

Comment: Hi user2680315, it looks like you haven't earned your Informed badge yet.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the application object, specifically the `offline` property. Depending on whether or not your site is offline, it will return `true` or `false`:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

if (Factory::getApplication()->get('offline'))
{
    // do this
}
else
{
    // do this other thing
}
```